SPFX Library - React Content Query Online
The official sample React Content Query Online stops working on Sharepoint Online.
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-content-query-online
I got a generic error:

Any Ideia?

If you check the browser's console output it might give you a hint as to what is wrong. Perhaps, something changed on the data source level. Maybe a list or a column was deleted.

there is nothing relevant in console and network. Even if you do a clone of the spfx and do a gulp serve, its not working
